# Python SQLite :IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

```
conn = database_connect()
if(conn is None):
    return None
cur = conn.cursor()
try:
    # Try executing the SQL and get from the database
    sql = """SELECT *
            FROM user
            WHERE user_id**strong text** =%s AND password =%s"""
    cur.execute(sql, (employee_id, password))
    r = cur.fetchone()# Fetch the first row
    rr = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()                     # Close the cursor
    conn.close()                    # Close the connection to the db

except:
# If there were any errors, return a NULL row printing an error to the debug
    print("Error Invalid Login")
    cur.close()                     # Close the cursor
    conn.close()                    # Close the connection to the db
    return None

user_info = []
if rr is None:
    print("worry")
    return []

for n in rr:
    user_info.append(n)

test = {
    'info1': user_info[0],
    'info2': user_info[1],
    'info3': user_info[2],
    'info4': user_info[3],
}

return test
```

Here is my code. First Implement the login function, and then get the user information, but there is a `IndexError: list index out of range`. How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you expecting 4 rows in your result set?

Comment: yes, like 4 rows in the dictionary

Comment: query your db and see the number of rows that comes back. It should give you the number of rows you are getting back in the object "rr", I guess you're receiving lesser rows than you are expecting.

Comment: how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
r = cur.fetchone()# Fetch the first row
rr = cur.fetchall()
```

The call to `fetchone()` will consume the first row, so `rr` will contain n-1 rows.

Also, if your database allow duplicated user_id then you have a serious db design issue - whether `user_id` is (suppoed to be) the primary key or the "username" (loging name), it should really be unique. If it isn't, then you want to change your schema, and if it is indeed unique then obviously your query can only return (at most !) one single row, in which case `rr` is garanteed to always be empty (since you consumed the first row with the `fetchone()` call.

As a side note, here are some possible improvements:

this :

```
for n in rr:
    user_info.append(n)
```

is completely useless - you are just building a shallow copy of `rr`, wo just work directly with `rr` instead.

Then do not assume you will always have four rows in your query result, so  at least build your `test` dict dynamically:

```
test = {}
# enumerate(seq) yields an index, value tuple
# for each value in `seq`.
for num, row in enumerate(rr, 1):
    key = "info{}.format(num)
    test[key] = row
```

or more succintly:

```
test = {"info{}".format(num):row for num, row in enumerate(rr, 1)}
```

Note that this dict doesn't add much value compared to `rr` - you have "info" keys instead of numeric indexes and that's about all, so you could just directly use the `rr` list instead.

Last but not least, your try/except clause is too broad (too much code in the try block),  the except clause will eat very valuable debugging information (the exact error message and the full traceback) and even worse, the error message you display assumes way too much about what really happens. Actually  you probably shouldn't even have an except clause here (at least not until you really know what errors can happen here AND be properly handled at this point) so better to let the error propagate (so you get the full error message and traceback), and use the `finally` clause to close your connection instead:

```
sql = """SELECT *
        FROM user
        WHERE user_id**strong text** =%s AND password =%s"""

try:
    cur.execute(sql, (employee_id, password))
    r = cur.fetchone()# Fetch the first row
    rr = cur.fetchall()
finally:
    # this will always be executed whatever happens in the try block
    cur.close()                     # Close the cursor
    conn.close()                    # Close the connection to the db
```